# Want to know how PollSCM pick the repo to poll in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops

The Job doesn't seem to get triggered by GIT commits, will the Pollscm pick the repo in the 'Pull src' stage below ? Or kindly let me know how to pass the repo to PollSCM, for the build to be triggered once the git repo has committed a change ?

```
 node( ) {
        properties([ 
            buildDiscarder(logRotator(artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '', daysToKeepStr: '', numToKeepStr: '40')),
            disableConcurrentBuilds(), 
            parameters([
                string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'BRANCH', trim: false), 
                ]), 
            pipelineTriggers([pollSCM('H/10 * * * *')])
        ])
        stage('Clean Workspace') {
            cleanWs deleteDirs: true
        }
        stage('Pull src') {
            git branch: env.BRANCH, credentialsId: 'git', url: 'git@github.com:something/something'
        }
        stage('Pack'){
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PollSCM picks the repo thats in the stage 'Pull src' automatically, I had an issue with my GIT credentials post correcting it, the above job worked fine, polled periodically as stated and ran the build on commits.